# При большой фоновой картинке, передвигаться по ней зажимая левую кнопку мыши!

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, background

Суть вопроса такова! Как сделать так, чтобы поставить на background огромную картинку, например: локацию местности, чтобы не было скролла, и передвигаться по картинке зажимая левую кнопку мыши, и двигая мышкой в сторону? 
[Видео пример](https://yadi.sk/i/KpJDWg3p3KBJu2)
Спасибо, жду Ваших рекомендаций и подсказок!

Comment: mousedown, mousemove, mouseup

Comment: Очень существенный ответ! уж лучше бы так написал $('#bcgrd).on('mousedown', function(){})

Comment: это не ответ, это напутствие)

Comment: я еще добавлю - `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Не самый простой вариант, но скорее всего правильный: использовать любую картографическую библиотеку, например leaflet или mapbox (пример: http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple-example1.html ).

Comment: спасибо, вроде то что нужно! Буду разбираться! Еще раз спасибо!